# Select all between ' and ' with a , in between with regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

What i have:

text(x1,'Oranges','Apples','Pineapples

text(x2,'Bananas','Monkey','NODATA

What i want to extract from above:

'Oranges','Apples'

'Bananas','Monkey'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be as simple as `/'(.*)'/g`, which will look for anything between two single quotes and group it. The `.*` will match greedily, so you may be better off using `\w` or something instead depending on your need.

Answer (score 0):

In notepad++ open the find dialog and

- **Find what:** `('[^']*',)+`
- select **Regular expression**
- Click **Find Next**

The regular expression looks for:

- something not `'`: `[^']*`
- that is surounded on the left by a `'` and `',` on the right:  `'[^']*',`
- and allows to match non empty groups of it: `(...)+`